# port is listening but server is not on

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, tableau-api

I installed a tableau server. I have verified it does listen at port 80 and 8850.

In AWS security groups, these two ports allows the same source ip range.

The ports are blocked by firewall so I use ssh tunneling to test the web servers:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:8850 me@<server_ip>
ssh -L 1234:localhost:80 me@<server_ip>
```

If I tunnel port 80 using ssh, I can see the web page using http://localhost:1234; but If I tunnel port 8850 using ssh, I cannot. It says cannot open page “localhost:1234” because server unexpectedly dropped the connection…

It is clear my Security group did not block me from seeing the page of 8850 because otherwise I cannot see page of 80 either.

netstat shows that 8850 is listening, then why I cannot see the page? ie. why the server of 8850 does not work?

Comment: I think the tableau server only allow connection from localhost? you can check this article for allowing remote access https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/service_remote.htm

Comment: @Adiii: what do you mean "tableau server only allow connection from localhost?" Thanks. I know in general TSM server:8850 can be accessed from other machine

Comment: I mean it bind with localhost, allow remote connection

Comment: @Adiii I found the reason. if I browse "https" : //localhost:1234 for 8850. not "http", it will work. I do not understand why 8850 need to use https. I thought only 443 need. anyway, using https the page is accessed now. Thank you.

Comment: Tableau server is just using https only for 8850 port and can find it easily from the documentations.